# Identify date range and merge into max and min dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data ( int, date , date types)

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  VALUES 
     (1700171048,'2020-12-21','2021-01-03'), 
     (1700171048,'2021-01-05','2021-01-12'), 
     (1700171048,'2021-01-13','2021-01-17'), 
     (1700171048,'2021-01-18','2021-01-19'),
     (1700171048,'2021-01-22','2021-01-27'),
     (1700171048,'2021-01-28','2021-02-17')
     
     (1700171049,'2020-12-21','2021-01-03'), 
     (1700171049,'2021-01-04','2021-01-05'), 
     (1700171049,'2021-01-06','2021-01-17'),
     (1700171049,'2021-01-18','2021-01-19'),
     (1700171049,'2021-01-20','2021-01-27'),
     (1700171049,'2021-01-28','2021-02-17')

 ) AS c (id1, st, endt )
```

I need output( i.e. if start and end dates are continuous then make it part of group )

```
 id1         st             endt
 1700171048 '2020-12-21' , '2021-01-03'
 1700171048 '2021-01-05' , '2021-01-19'
 1700171048 '2021-01-22' , '2021-02-17'

 1700171049 '2020-12-21' to '2021-02-17'
```

I tried this, won't work.

```
    select id, case when min(b.st) = max(b.endt) + 1 then min(b.st) end,
            case when min(b.endt) = min(b.st) + 1 then max(b.st) end 
     from c a  join c b
   group by id
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please indicate what RDBMS you're using (MySQL, MSSQL, Oracle, ...) and version.  Especially when it comes to working with dates, there are differences between RDBMS solutions.  Also your desired output doesn't really explain (to me) what you're trying accomplish.  Please use words to beef up our understanding of your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  Use `lag()` to identify if there is an overlap.  Then a cumulative sum of when there is no overlaps and aggregation:

```
select id1, min(st), max(endt)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_endt >= st + interval '-1 day' then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by id1 order by st) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(endt) over (partition by id1 order by st) as prev_endt
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by id1, grp;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d1c0cdf877e78efa5363e006d8625fa6) is a db<>fiddle.